# Linear algebra : what is a derived matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives

I'm learning linear algebra with the help of a very good book.
But another one, targeting machine learning, wrote:

*If **f** is a differentiable function of a real variable, and **A** a differentiable matrix then**:

$$ d[f(A)] = (df)(A) \land dA $$

But my linear algebra book doesn't speak about those matrices.
Could they have another name that would talk more to me?
Because it's the first time I heard about them... (but I haven't a great level in mathematics)

What are they, if you can tell me a bit about them and especially give me one or two of their goals?

Thanks !

---

- in case I'd made a translation error, here the original text in French: "*Si **f** est une fonction d'une variable réelle dérivable et **A** une matrice dérivable, alors*"

Comment: A priori j'aurais dit que c'est une fonction $A$ à valeurs matricielles et différentiable, mais j'ai des doutes sur ton bouquin : c'est quoi ? (Très suspect de dire que $f$ est une fonction d'une variable réelle et $A$ une matrice puis d'écrire $f(A)$).

Comment: Translation of my comment above: *A priori* I'd say it is a function $A$ with matrix values, and which is differentiable. But I have some doubts about your book: which one is it? (It is very suspect to say that $f$ is a function of a real variable and $A$ is a matrix, and then write $f(A)$.)